# extract lines from image OpenCvSharp

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing

Here i am trying to trace lines from image.
i used below steps

1. threshold image
2. dilate image
3. thinning of image
4. findcontours from image

here i am getting vector lines at the both sides of edges of line. but i want to generate a single vector line at the middle of each line.

Any one one help me how to do this.

below is the result i got.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a thinning algorithm.  A thinning algorithm basically takes a thick line and finds the middle (depending on the impelmentation) so you're left with a single line.

So you'd do something like this.

1. Load Image
2. Threshold Image
3. Dilate Image
4. Thin Image with some type of skeleton algorithm.

Here are a few links on thinning.  They're not OpenCvSharp but could be ported.

Answers.OpenCV

http://answers.opencv.org/question/3207/what-is-a-good-thinning-algorithm-for-getting-the-skeleton-of-characters-for-ocr/

OpenCV-Code Blog by Nashruddin Amin

http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-thinning-algorithm-in-opencv/

http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-guo-hall-thinning-algorithm/